# What is the difference between RELATION "AND" and "OR" in TAX_QUERY?

Tags: wp-query

Because if I use:

`'relation' => 'AND'`

or

`'relation' => 'OR'`

the results are always the same. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tax_query` is a 2-dimensional array, each sub-array can be considered to be a taxonomy query, typical its of the form:

```
array(
  'taxonomy' => 'people',
  'field' => 'slug',
  'terms' => 'bob'
)
```

(e.g. posts in with the term with slug 'bob', of the 'people' taxonomy).

The fact that `tax_query` is a two dimensional array means that you can have *multiple* taxonomy queries. In this case you may want to return posts which match **all** taxonomy queries (`relation => 'AND'` ) or posts which match **at least one** taxonomy query (`relation => 'OR'` ).

As the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):
 states

> This construct allows you to query multiple taxonomies by using the relation parameter in the first (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the taxonomy queries.

For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', //Must satisfy all taxonomy queries
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'action'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

returns all posts with `move_genre` term with slug 'action' **AND** does not have the `actor` terms with IDs `103`,`115`,`206`.

On the other hand (notice `relation` change):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',//Must satisfy at least one taxonomy query
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'action'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

returns all posts with either have `move_genre` term with slug 'action' **OR** do not have the `actor` terms with IDs `103`,`115`,`206` (or satisfy both).

Comment: If every post which matches one of the taxonomy queries matches all the others too, there'll be no difference in returned posts between `relation` set to `OR` and `AND`. This is trivially true in the case where you only have one taxonomy query.

Answer (score 5):

With `AND` the returned posts must have *both* terms.

With `OR` the returned posts need only have one or the other.

If they are returning the same then your posts you are querying probably all have both terms.